# Edit the value inside the JSON array with Github Actions

Tags: javascript, json, github, continuous-integration, github-actions

I have a JSON like this stored in the folder/path where my Github action is executed -

```
{
   "version":"1",
   "sampleArray":[
      {
         "id":"1"
      }
   ],
   "secondArray":[
      {
         "secondId":"2"
      }
   ]
}
```

Using Github actions how can I edit the value of `id` eg: make the `id` value as "5" inside the `sampleArray` so that my JSON has an updated value?

Comment: you could use the `jq` command available in most linux distros, but this depends on the image that was selected on the build.

Comment: @SamridhTuladhar Can you please give me an example

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [jq](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/) command line tool to edit the json file in place like this :

```yaml
on: [push, pull_request]
name: Build
jobs:
  build:
    name: Example
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v1
      - name: Update config.json
        run: echo "`jq '.sampleArray[0].id="5"' config.json`" > config.json
      - name: read config.json
        run: cat config.json
```

You can also use it with [sponge](https://manpages.debian.org/testing/moreutils/sponge.1.en.html#:%7E:text=sponge%20reads%20standard%20input%20and,file%20if%20it%20already%20exists.) from the moreutils package and pass an environment variable in the following example :

```yaml
on: [push, pull_request]
name: Build
jobs:
  build:
    name: Example
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v1
      - name: install more-utils
        run: sudo apt-get install moreutils
      - name: Update config.json
        env:
          ID: 5
        run: jq --arg id "$ID" '.sampleArray[0].id=$id' config.json | sponge config.json
      - name: read config.json
        run: cat config.json
```

which would output :

```json
{
    "version": "1",
    "sampleArray": [{
        "id": "5"
    }],
    "secondArray": [{
        "secondId": "2"
    }]
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer :) But echo "`jq '.sampleArray[0].id="5"' config.json`" > config.json is modifying the json file to empty.

Comment: @Maria both solution above worked for me in github actions, do you have any error in the logs ? maybe it has to do with the structure of your json vs jq query [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aOA1Q.png)